# Radially averaged 1D power spectrum from 2D data using FFTW3

Tags: c++, fftw, spectrum

**GOAL**

I have 2d data that represent a **real** scalar field `f(x,y)` and I want to calculate the 1D spectrum in the `fourier (q) space`.

My project is written mainly in C++ but there are some blocks of code in C. I am also using the FFTW3 library and perform in-place transforms.

**CODE**

I have written a code to test some basic signals.

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

double PI = 4*atan(1.0); 

int WrapAround(int k, int N)
{
  if (k <= N/2)
    return k;
  else
    return k-N;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  if (argc <= 1 or argc >= 3)
    {
      std::cout << "One argument is needed: Degrees of freedom per dimension. Preferably power of 2. Exiting..." << std::endl;
      exit(-1);
    }
  
  /* Generate x and y axis */
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
  int N = strtol(argv[1], nullptr, 0);
  double Lx = 2*PI; //length of box
  double Ly = Lx;   
  double dx = Lx/N;
  double dy = Ly/N;
  std::vector<double> x,y;
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    x.push_back(i*dx);
  y = x;
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
    
  /* Define data for which the power spectrum will be calculated */
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
  double* field = new double[N*N]{};
  std::cout << "Field is: " << std::endl;
  for (int j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
      for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
      /* test different cases here */
      //field[ i + N*j ] = 1.;
      field[ i + N*j ] = 4.0 * sin(3.0*x[i]);
      //field[ i + N*j ] = 4.0 * cos(1.0*y[j]);
      //field[ i + N*j ] = 5.0 * sin(-x[i] + 3.0*y[j]) + 3.0 * sin(x[i] + 3.0*y[j]);
      //field[ i + N*j ] = 2.0 * sin( 3.0*(2*PI*x[i]/Lx) + 3.0*(2*PI*y[j]/Ly) );        
      std::cout << field[ i + N*j ] << "\t"; 
    }
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }std::cout << std::endl;
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */

  /* Prepare in-place fft */
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
  int blockSize = N*(N+2);
  fftw_plan x2k, k2x;
  double* IN = (double*) fftw_malloc( sizeof(double)*blockSize );
  fftw_complex* OUT = (fftw_complex*) IN;
  x2k = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N,N,IN,OUT,FFTW_MEASURE);
  k2x = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(N,N,OUT,IN,FFTW_MEASURE);
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
  
  /* Fill the allocated block pointed by the pointer "in" with the field data */
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
  for (int j=0; j<N; j++){
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
      IN[ i + j*(N+2) ] = field[ i + N*j ]; //note the (N+2) term 
  }
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */

  /* Execute FFT */
  fftw_execute(x2k);

  /* Fill a buffer with the power spectrum values */
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
  double* powSpec = new double[N*(N/2+1)]{};
  double Re,Im,val,q1,q2;
  std::cout << "Power spectrum values: " << std::endl;
  for (int k2=0; k2<N; k2++){
    q2 = WrapAround(k2,N);
    for (int k1=0; k1<N/2+1; k1++){
      q1 = k1;
      Re = IN[ (N+2)*k2 + 2*k1 ];
      Im = IN[ (N+2)*k2 + 2*k1+1 ];
      val = (Re*Re + Im*Im) / pow(N,4); // normalize
      powSpec[ (N/2+1)*k2 + k1 ] = val; 
      
      // Now print the buffer
      if (val < 1e-16)
        val = 0.0;
      std::cout << "(" << q1 << "," << q2 << ")\t";
      std::cout << "(" << k1 << "," << k2 << ")\t" << val << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }std::cout << std::endl;
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */

  /* Execute inverse FFT */
  fftw_execute(k2x);
  
  /* Print result of inverse FFT */
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
  std::cout << "After applying inverse FFT: " << std::endl;
  for (int k2=0; k2<N; k2++){
    for (int k1=0; k1<N; k1++){
      std::cout << IN[ (N+2)*k2 + k1 ] << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }std::cout << std::endl;
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */

  /* Radial averaging */
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
  double dk = 2*PI/Lx;
  double factor = pow(dk,2);  
  int qdiagMax = floor( sqrt( pow(dk*N/2,2) + pow(dk*N/2,2) ) ) + 1;
  int qbin;
  double qSquared;
  double* S1D = new double[qdiagMax]{}; // buffer to contain 1D spectrum
  double* DoS = new double[qdiagMax]{}; // buffer to contain the density of states
  for (int k2=0; k2<N; k2++){
    q2 = WrapAround(k2,N); 
    for (int k1=0; k1<N/2; k1++){
      q1 = WrapAround(k1,N);
      qSquared = factor * (q1*q1 + q2*q2);
      qbin = floor(sqrt(qSquared));
      S1D[qbin] += powSpec[ N/2*k2 + k1 ];
      DoS[qbin] ++;
    }
  }
  DoS[0] = 1; //the first grid point on its own bin
  DoS[qdiagMax-1] = 1; // the last grid point on its own bin
  //the two lines above are wrong and inner loop must go up to N/2+1. (EDIT)
  for (int i=0; i<qdiagMax; i++)
    S1D[i] /= DoS[i];
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */

  /* Print results of radial averaging */
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
  double printOut;
  std::cout << "Radially averaged power spectrum: " << std::endl;
  for (int i=0; i<qdiagMax; i++)
    {
      printOut = S1D[i];
      if ( S1D[i] < 1e-16 ) printOut = 0;
      std::cout << printOut << "\t";
    }std::cout << "\n" <<std::endl;

  std::cout << "Density of states: " << std::endl;
  for (int i=0; i<qdiagMax; i++)
    std::cout << DoS[i] << "\t";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  /* ----------------------------------------------------------- */
  
  /* Destroy plan & release resources */
  fftw_destroy_plan(x2k);
  fftw_free(IN);
  OUT = nullptr;
  IN  = nullptr;
  return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

Let's look at the case where `field[ i + N*j ] = 4.0 * sin(3.0*x[i]);`.
We expect a non zero value in the position `(3,0)`. Note that the first parentheses
refer to the `q` values in Fourier space, and `k` is just the index. The `y`
direction is wrapped around. Let's execute `./a.out 8`

```
Field is: 
0   2.82843 -4  2.82843 1.46958e-15 -2.82843    4   -2.82843    
0   2.82843 -4  2.82843 1.46958e-15 -2.82843    4   -2.82843    
0   2.82843 -4  2.82843 1.46958e-15 -2.82843    4   -2.82843    
0   2.82843 -4  2.82843 1.46958e-15 -2.82843    4   -2.82843    
0   2.82843 -4  2.82843 1.46958e-15 -2.82843    4   -2.82843    
0   2.82843 -4  2.82843 1.46958e-15 -2.82843    4   -2.82843    
0   2.82843 -4  2.82843 1.46958e-15 -2.82843    4   -2.82843    
0   2.82843 -4  2.82843 1.46958e-15 -2.82843    4   -2.82843    

Power spectrum values: 
(0,0)   (0,0)   0   (1,0)   (1,0)   0   (2,0)   (2,0)   0   (3,0)   (3,0)   4   (4,0)   (4,0)   0   
(0,1)   (0,1)   0   (1,1)   (1,1)   0   (2,1)   (2,1)   0   (3,1)   (3,1)   0   (4,1)   (4,1)   0   
(0,2)   (0,2)   0   (1,2)   (1,2)   0   (2,2)   (2,2)   0   (3,2)   (3,2)   0   (4,2)   (4,2)   0   
(0,3)   (0,3)   0   (1,3)   (1,3)   0   (2,3)   (2,3)   0   (3,3)   (3,3)   0   (4,3)   (4,3)   0   
(0,4)   (0,4)   0   (1,4)   (1,4)   0   (2,4)   (2,4)   0   (3,4)   (3,4)   0   (4,4)   (4,4)   0   
(0,-3)  (0,5)   0   (1,-3)  (1,5)   0   (2,-3)  (2,5)   0   (3,-3)  (3,5)   0   (4,-3)  (4,5)   0   
(0,-2)  (0,6)   0   (1,-2)  (1,6)   0   (2,-2)  (2,6)   0   (3,-2)  (3,6)   0   (4,-2)  (4,6)   0   
(0,-1)  (0,7)   0   (1,-1)  (1,7)   0   (2,-1)  (2,7)   0   (3,-1)  (3,7)   0   (4,-1)  (4,7)   0   

After applying inverse FFT: 
6.31089e-30 181.019 -256    181.019 9.40529e-14 -181.019    256 -181.019    
6.31089e-30 181.019 -256    181.019 9.40529e-14 -181.019    256 -181.019    
6.31089e-30 181.019 -256    181.019 9.40529e-14 -181.019    256 -181.019    
6.31089e-30 181.019 -256    181.019 9.40529e-14 -181.019    256 -181.019    
6.31089e-30 181.019 -256    181.019 9.40529e-14 -181.019    256 -181.019    
6.31089e-30 181.019 -256    181.019 9.40529e-14 -181.019    256 -181.019    
6.31089e-30 181.019 -256    181.019 9.40529e-14 -181.019    256 -181.019    
6.31089e-30 181.019 -256    181.019 9.40529e-14 -181.019    256 -181.019    

Radially averaged power spectrum: 
0   0   0   0.363636    0   0   

Density of states: 
1   5   9   11  5   1
```

The value that I get is 4, whereas I would expect to have 16, since power is the amplitude squared. Do I have to multiply by a factor of 4? Is it something similar with the 1D case, where, for example in the time-domain there are no negative frequencies and we multiply by 2 because of the `exp(-it)` term?

**RADIALLY AVERAGED 1D SPECTRUM**

My question here is if it is implemented correctly because I am afraid that I am missing a factor. For example, since the transform is in-place, I only have the 1st and 4th quadrants in
Fourier space. Do I have to multiply by two at the end? It seems like the frequency appears in the correct bin, but is the value correct?

The code is long but I think clean enough, so if there is anyone experienced in signal analysis that can devote some time to help with a correct implementation of this 1D spectrum, I would be most grateful.

Comment: As an engineer I always ignore that constant in the (I)FFT; I know that conventions differ.

Comment: As a theoretical physicist I believe in nothing more than in constants. You are missing the amplitude from the 2nd and 3rd frequency space quadrants. As you point out yourself correctly. Just compare the results to when you fill the quadrants with their respective complex conjugate.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour As a computational physicist who admires theory, I find it at least frustrating when the numerical results do not agree with the theory (when this is possible). What you propose is my next step, to consider the other quadrants by filling up a bigger buffer. But why not just multiply by 4? However, this won't be accurate if the "signal" has only ky frequencies. And also, what about the multiplication by 2 in the radial average?

Comment: Completely agree with your calculation to arrive at 4. I was just motivating the 2 factor by missing amplitudes. The radial average accounts for the rest.